# Ender 3 first layer inconsistent layer lines

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting, bltouch

I was running my Ender 3 just fine with good first-layer adhesion/everything else but my setup changed after my Pi SD card got corrupted so I had to re-install and reconfigure my bed leveling via OctoPrint. After this my first layer started to look like this:

[image: Image of 3D print first layer]
* this is the bottom of the completed print

IIRC I changed the following (and have tried undoing it but to no avail):

- Increased extruder tension (since it was skipping while retracting)
- Lowered z-probe offset (since re-calibrating it was too high)

This is with PLA

Running a modified Ender3 w/

- BL Touch
- Micro Swiss Direct Drive Extruder for Creality CR-10 / Ender 3 Printers
- PEI Plate
- BIGTREETECH SKR Mini E3 V1.2 Control Board w/ Marlin dev built 20210609

Sliced on Cura 4.11.0

- Printing Temp: 210.0 °C
- Bed Temp: 60 °C
- First Layer printing speed: 20.0 mm/s
- First layer acceleration: 500.0 mm/s^2
- No first-layer fan (or any cooling at any point)

I've tried:

- Increasing initial Z-offset; this doesn't work since it will affect my bed adhesion to the point the print will pop off
- Adjusting extrusion gear tension; will start skipping on retraction/no-luck

After the first couple of imperfect layers get ironed over, the upper layers will not have any extrusion problems, or whatever this is, and are basically fine.

Comment: This has been asked before, but I can't find the question. I think the nozzle is too close to the bed. Will try to find it!

Comment: Yeah this is it, it's strange because I'd never seen an extrusion pattern like this. Anyways after opting for higher rather than lower and swapping to a glass bed so it would be flatter I was more easily able to get this tuned in. If you want to write/link to the other answer as an answer I would be willing to accept it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find the other question, but know it exists. Please write your own answer and accept it after 48 hours. We can always mark it later as a duplicate when i have found the question. It is good to have duplicates because this issue is hard to capture in a question title and key words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, the nozzle was set too low and was causing pressure buildup at certain points since the PEI plate wasn't perfectly flat.

After raising it and swapping for a glass bed I was able to stop this behavior.

**Note:** While this helped this issue a little bit, it was also making adhesion really poor on faster prints. A better fix I found was that I recently swapped filament spools, it looks like the average spool thickness was greater than the previous one, and after reducing the flow 5 %. I was able to eliminate this problem entirely, thanks to the question [What is causing 'droplets' on first layer?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/5372/)